# Ansible map filter from a registered var output

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, ansible-inventory

I'm getting with ansible through a registered variable a full copy of the dhcpd.leases file from one server. The output with ansible debug looks like this:

```
TASK [Show passive storage nodes info] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [10.241.55.2] => {
    "msg": [
        "# The format of this file is documented in the dhcpd.leases(5) manual page.",
        "# This lease file was written by isc-dhcp-4.2.2",
        "",
        "lease 10.241.55.165 {",
        "  starts 4 2019/12/12 09:30:37;",
        "  ends 4 2019/12/12 21:30:37;",
        "  tstp 4 2019/12/12 21:30:37;",
        "  cltt 4 2019/12/12 09:30:37;",
        "  binding state free;",
        "  hardware ethernet b4:d1:35:00:04:50;",
        "  uid \"\\001\\264\\3215\\000\\004P\";",
        "}",
        "lease 10.241.55.163 {",
        "  starts 1 2019/12/16 08:10:56;",
        "  ends 1 2019/12/16 20:10:56;",
        "  tstp 1 2019/12/16 20:10:56;",
        "  cltt 1 2019/12/16 08:10:56;",
        "  binding state free;",
        "  hardware ethernet b4:d1:35:00:03:d7;",
        "}",
        "lease 10.241.55.159 {",
        "  starts 1 2019/12/16 08:52:20;",
        "  ends 1 2019/12/16 20:52:20;",
        "  tstp 1 2019/12/16 20:52:20;",
        "  cltt 1 2019/12/16 08:52:20;",
        "  binding state free;",
        "  hardware ethernet b4:d1:35:00:03:b4;",
        "}",
        "lease 10.241.55.166 {",
        "  starts 1 2019/12/16 08:54:38;",
        "  ends 1 2019/12/16 20:54:38;",
        "  tstp 1 2019/12/16 20:54:38;",
        "  cltt 1 2019/12/16 08:54:38;",
        "  binding state free;",
        "  hardware ethernet b4:d1:35:00:04:63;",
        "}",
        "lease 10.241.55.164 {",
        "  starts 1 2019/12/16 10:48:10;",
        "  ends 1 2019/12/16 22:48:10;",
        "  tstp 1 2019/12/16 22:48:10;",
        "  cltt 1 2019/12/16 10:48:10;",
        "  binding state free;",
        "  hardware ethernet b4:d1:35:00:04:4e;",
        "}",
        "lease 10.241.55.143 {",
        "  starts 5 2020/02/14 04:38:09;",
        "  ends 5 2020/02/14 16:38:09;",
        "  cltt 5 2020/02/14 04:38:09;",
        "  binding state active;",
        "  next binding state free;",
        "  rewind binding state free;",
        "  hardware ethernet 08:94:ef:9c:80:4a;",
        "  client-hostname \"linux-compute-e7d573cb9fda4e689939e21a7843c4fb\";",
        "}",
        "lease 10.241.55.148 {",
        "  starts 5 2020/02/14 05:03:08;",
        "  ends 5 2020/02/14 17:03:08;",
        "  cltt 5 2020/02/14 05:03:08;",
        "  binding state active;",
        "  next binding state free;",
        "  rewind binding state free;",
        "  hardware ethernet 00:e0:ec:ca:44:84;",
        "  client-hostname \"linux-storage-4391fc6548764de5a15a46b432d3cd37\";",
        "}",
        "lease 10.241.55.235 {",
        "  starts 5 2020/02/14 05:20:28;",
        "  ends 5 2020/02/14 17:20:28;",
        "  cltt 5 2020/02/14 05:20:28;",
        "  binding state active;",
        "  next binding state free;",
        "  rewind binding state free;",
        "  hardware ethernet 00:e0:ec:ca:45:74;",
        "  client-hostname \"linux-storage-58aba44ac09d4f639b9374b9142b1a53\";",
        "}",
        "lease 10.241.55.141 {",
        "  starts 5 2020/02/14 06:01:04;",
        "  ends 5 2020/02/14 18:01:04;",
        "  cltt 5 2020/02/14 06:01:04;",
        "  binding state active;",
        "  next binding state free;",
        "  rewind binding state free;",
        "  hardware ethernet 08:94:ef:9c:80:6c;",
        "  client-hostname \"linux-compute-d228bc79357c4c8b87c280f9efae6ba6\";",
        "}",
        "lease 10.241.55.236 {",
        "  starts 5 2020/02/14 06:12:28;",
        "  ends 5 2020/02/14 18:12:28;",
        "  cltt 5 2020/02/14 06:12:28;",
        "  binding state active;",
        "  next binding state free;",
        "  rewind binding state free;",
        "  hardware ethernet 00:e0:ec:ca:45:75;",
        "  client-hostname \"linux-storage-58aba44ac09d4f639b9374b9142b1a53\";",
        "}",
        "lease 10.241.55.140 {",
        "  starts 5 2020/02/14 06:13:18;",
        "  ends 5 2020/02/14 18:13:18;",
        "  cltt 5 2020/02/14 06:13:18;",
        "  binding state active;",
        "  next binding state free;",
        "  rewind binding state free;",
        "  hardware ethernet 08:94:ef:9c:80:24;",
        "  client-hostname \"linux-compute-d0a9a76a7b5249048f78642220a1958c\";",
        "}",
```

Is there anyway to map the filed lease ip + client-hostname then based on that to do filtering and put strictly the ips in an inventory file? I know I can get the ips directly but there are servers which have 4 ips so they have the same hostname. Rather than put all 4 ips in the inventory I only need one of their ips (doesn't matter which one) and I'm trying to make the filtering based on the hostname. Also there are entries in the output that have no client-hostname so ideally those should be ignored.

The question is similar with another one I've posted here:
[Ansible jina2 template, filter output based on uniqueness](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60206448/ansible-jina2-template-filter-output-based-on-uniqueness?noredirect=1#comment106497373_60206448)

But with this, I'm trying a different approach.

What I've tried so far is this:

```
 debug:
   msg: "{{ p_storage_ips.stdout | map(attribute='client-hostname' | list) }}"
```

But I get nothing:
TASK [Show passive storage nodes info]

```
ok: [10.241.55.2] => {
    "msg": "<generator object do_map at 0x7f40e52785f0>"
}
```

Also tried like this:

```
   - set_fact:
       dhcp_hosts: "{{ dhcp.stdout_lines | selectattr('client-hostname', 'defined') | map(attribute='lease') | list }}"
```

Any help would be really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I've figured out that it would be way easier to filter the output sent to ansible directly from bash. In the end I came up with this:

```
 awk '!seen[$0]++' /var/lib/dhcp/dhcpd.leases | grep -vE -- 'ends|starts|tstp|cltt|uid|bind|hardware' | grep -B1 storage | awk '{print $2}' | grep '^[0-9]'
```

Which results in 2 ip addresses for the storage nodes (out of 8).

```
10.241.55.148
10.241.55.235
```

This doesn't solve the initial question but at least provides the desired answer.